# How to use pandas to extract two values from csv at the same time? (two columns, same row)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I am using `pandas` to read a csv file into my python code. I understand I can grab a specific value from a specific column for all rows and append it to an array as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('File.txt')
for row in df[df.columns[0]]:
    playerNames.append(row)
```

However, I want to, instead, grab the values from columns 0 and 2 at the same time to populate a dictionary. In my head it would be something like:

```
for row in df[df.columns[0,2]]:
    playerNameDictionary[row.columns[0]] = row.columns[2]
```

Obviously this wrong (don't even think it compiles) but I am just at a loss as to how I would go about doing this.

Answer (score 2):

```
dict_sample = dict(zip(df.column1, df.column2))
```

column1 & column 2 stands for the column names. It will create a key value pair with key being column1 data and value being column2 data. I hope I understood the question right.

Answer (score 1):

Loops are anti-pattern for Pandas. More efficiently, you can use [`pd.Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
key_col, val_col  = df.columns[[0, 2]]

playerNameDictionary = df.set_index(key_col)[val_col].to_dict()
```

Comment: and this will do it for every row? No need to loop through it?

Comment: @AlekPiasecki, Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your future keys are not duplicate.
For Python <3

```
my_dict ={}
for key, value in zip(df.column0, df.column2)):
    my_dict [key] = value
```

For Python 3>

```
my_dict = dict(zip(df.column0, df.column2))
```

Comment: and this will do it for every row? No need to loop through it?

Comment: Yes do give a try